# What is the getLoggerRepository() method equivalent in 2.x

Tags: log4j2

we are currently using 1.x and have the following in the code

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
Logger rLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
Logger fileWriter = rLogger.getLoggerRepository().exists("name");
```

we are working on upgrading log4j to version 2.x and it looks like getLoggerRepository() is not supported in 2.x.
looking for some help for equivalent code/methods to use in 2.x.

greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: How about `LogManager.exists("name")? LogManager.getLogger("name") : null`?

Comment: i will give that a try and see if it works. Thanks